# Reputation graph shows the great year of '9

Tags: bug, reputation-history, reputation-graph

My reputation graph:
https://stackoverflow.com/users/23528/daniel-a-white?tab=reputation&sort=graph

Looks like the leading zero function isn't working:

[image]

Dur.

Comment: Apparently you really have been on here for forever ;)

Comment: @NathanOliver not as long as some - my user id is ~23k. I got in at the public beta.

Comment: Are you worried about confusing '9 with perhaps '95 or '98? Maybe we should just call it '10 to be safe.

Comment: @TravisJ i was concern that it would be 19, 29, etc.

Comment: @DanielA.White that was a joke about windows 10.

Comment: This is why we need left-pad in NPM :p

Comment: I'm a bit confused - how does this get any downvotes? It's a bug that's clearly a bug...

Comment: [For the ones that don't get Travis J joke](http://www.extremetech.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/windows-10-skipped-9-reddit-95.jpg)

Comment: I was wondering why mine didn't say Aug '016 actually